# Google drive: authorize single account without logging into google?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm writing a php application that needs to upload to google drive, but only ever to one account, that needs to be hard coded in without having to ask a user to type in credentials. I'm looking for a way to programmatically enter credentials and/or an access token for the account that I can store in my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I authorise a background web app without user intervention? (canonical ?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical)

Comment: @Dagon Ah thank you... I don't know why I didn't see it :/... Time to CV :(